PowerApps patch function. Can you do a database insert via a SQL view?
I am learning PowerApps to interface with a SQL database. My organization uses the MS 365 platform, but it actually needs the power of a SQL database. PowerApps is marketed as a low/no code tool, but as soon as you want to do moderately fancy stuff with a SQL database, it becomes very difficult, at least for me.
The "ultimate" record updating tool in PowerApps is the patch() function. I'm used to using SQL views to insert or update the database. But when I try to use patch() with a datasource which is linked to a view, I can only read the database (select statements), I can't write to the database. Is there a workaround for this?
I can create a PowerApps datasource with a "virtual table", e.g. that is created by a view, but I can't update the datasource using a patch() statement. What am I doing wrong?

Never tried SQL with patch but see if this Power Platform Community post can help you, it's about Patch Problem with SQL gateway
